# Can Leia sense disturbances in the Force on a planetary scale?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

We know Leia is a Force sensitive. Her innate, untrained abilities is sufficient to sense those she is close to, like how Yoda experienced during Order 66.

We also know Obi-Wan can sense disturbances in the Force during the destruction of Alderaan, even though he was not really close to any of them, because millions of lives died so suddenly and horribly.

Is Leia sensitive enough for that?

> I don't know if Leia is a trained Force user in canon, but novelisations show she knew precisely what happened when she felt what she did when her son murdered his father, so I would argue she is at least more attuned than before. Additionally, she would have been subconsciously familiar with the type of disturbance in the Force caused by a heavily inhabited planet's destruction - traumas leave strong impressions if you don't suffer amnesia from it. As a Rebellion leader and former Senator, she'd likely be familiar and possibly close to some New Republic politicians and officers too. Overall, there are grounds to suggest Leia would sense the destruction of the Republic system that blew up in the sky yet again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)), she did indeed sense the destruction of the Hosnian System

> He looked to his right, suddenly alarmed, as Leia swayed where she was standing. “General, are you all right?”
>
> Leaning against a console for support, she steadied herself. **“A great
> disturbance—in the Force. Deaths and passings. Too much death, too
> many passings.”**
>
> Straightening, her expression grim, she walked over to confront the
> wiry, slight Admiral Statura. Despite his experience in battle, he was
> left as shaken by the revelation as anyone else in the room. What had
> just happened could scarcely be comprehended.

Comment: I wonder, is this sufficient indication of formal Force training to any degree? She's starting to sound like good ol' Ben Kenobi and even a slight bit of Yoda.